# How do you change the current keyboard layout from the terminal?

Tags: bash, keyboard, shortcuts, layout

I'm trying to create a script to assign each keyboard layout to a different keyboard shortcut, seeing as to how I'm using way too many of them to go through them one at a time whenever I need a specific one. How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setxkbmap`:

`setexkbmap [langauge code]` (Langauge code could be `en`, etc)